# Light through micro-perforation

Tags: visible-light

I am trying to have a metal film with micro-perforation lit from one side by LED so that only the perforated pattern appears on the other.

Example: Misfit Shine[image]

How do I calculate the film thickness, hole size and spacing(perforation) in order to get to prototyping?

Comment: The pattern is clearly visible on these devices and most of the images that I can find online... if you want less visibility, you will have to chose a film with less transparency, i.e. closer to probably 99% than 90% attenuation, but this will greatly attenuate the light from the LEDs. In any case, we are the wrong people to ask. You need to ask the shop that makes these films what/how they can do this. This is not a physics but an actual industrial engineering question.

Comment: This isn't a physics question so much as an engineering question.

Comment: [This question is a good fit for us over on Engineering SE](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/8110/368).